# Decoding pdf object streams in java

Tags: java, pdf

I've been trying to decode object streams encoded with Flatedecode using the following code.

```
    public class test2 {

    public static byte[] decodeStream(byte[] stream) {
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
        inflater.setInput(stream);
        byte[] decoded = new byte[1024];
        int result = 0;
        try {
            result = inflater.inflate(decoded);
        } catch (DataFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result > 0 ? decoded : null;
    }

    public static void findstream(String text) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\n<<[^\r\n]+>>stream\\r\\n");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String matched = matcher.group();
            int offset = matcher.end();
            int length = Integer.parseInt(matched.trim().split("\\s")[1].split("/")[0]);
            byte[] compressed = text.substring(offset, offset + length).getBytes();
            System.out.println(new String(decodeStream(compressed)));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        File file = new File("F:\\users\\public\\Downloads", "P887906-01.pdf");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        FileInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (in == null) System.exit(0);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        try {
            int count = in.read(buffer);
            if (count > 0) findstream(new String(buffer));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

As I understand, the problem is with the dictionary, since the needDictionary is set to true after i used the inflate method, but i really don't know how to fix it.  Please help me understand what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a library for this?

Comment: This is how i learned to do it.  if there is another way i would love to know about it.

Comment: I can see many issue with this what exactly is your problem . Firstly you are not deflating it then why are you inflating it ? ParseInt that you using can also have a non numeric String . What exactly do you want to do and what is the problem. There are couple that I have pointed out.

Comment: ` byte[] compressed = text.substring(offset, offset + length).getBytes();` is not compressed .

Comment: As i understand it, the inflate is for decompressing and deflate is for compressing (or am i wrong?), and the streams are compressed.   For the last two point, thanks, but they don't bother me for now since this is only a test code.

Comment: @user212263 *I've been trying to decode object streams encoded with Flatedecode using the following code* - and what was the result? Without knowing how something is *broken*, it is hard to *fix*.

Comment: The method decodeStream returns 0.

Comment: The result of the program is NullPointerException which is caused by using the System.out.println on an empy byte array (which does not suppose to be empyt)